# React Native - Getting the `location` state in my React Redux Store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-maps

I'm trying to get my `location` (Longitude and Latitude) state in my React Redux Store to create multiple of MapView Marker but it returns this error:

[image]

Here are my codes:

EventMap.js - this is where I want to use the Redux State and to create multiple MapView Marker. I tried to apply the Redux State in coordinate of `MapView.Marker`.

```
this.state = {
  focusedLocation: {
    latitude: 0,
    longitude: 0,
    // latitudeDelta: 0.04864195044303443,
    // longitudeDelta: 0.040142817690068,
    latitudeDelta: 0.01,
    longitudeDelta: Dimensions.get('window').width / Dimensions.get('window').height * 0.01
  },
  },
  markers: [
    {
      coordinate: {
        latitude: 37.42484589323653,
        longitude: -122.08271104842426
      },
    },
    {
      coordinate: {
        latitude: 37.42019338901534,
        longitude: -122.08207536488771
      },

    },
    {
      coordinate: {
        latitude: 37.4219108525511,
        longitude: -122.08126466721296
      },
    },
    {
      coordinate: {
        latitude: 37.42190153308783,
        longitude: -122.08728086203337
      },
    },
    {
      coordinate: {
        latitude: 37.419681603891306,
        longitude: -122.08521489053966
      },
    }
  ],
}

<MapView
      style={styles.container}
      initialRegion={this.state.focusedLocation}
      onPress={this.pickLocationHandler}
      showsUserLocation={true}
      ref={ref => this.map = ref} //For animating map movement
    >
      {userMarker}
      {this.props.events.map((marker, index) => {
        if(marker.location) {
          const scaleStyle = {
            transform: [
              {
                scale: interpolations[index].scale,
              },
            ],
          };
          const opacityStyle = {
            opacity: interpolations[index].opacity,
          };
          return (
            <MapView.Marker key={index} coordinate={marker.location}>
              <Animated.View style={[styles.markerWrap, opacityStyle]}>
                <Animated.View style={[styles.ring, scaleStyle]} />
                  <View style={styles.marker} />
              </Animated.View>
            </MapView.Marker>
          );
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      })}
    </MapView>

---------------
const mapStateToProps = state => {
return {
  events: state.events.events
};
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EventMap);
```

EventCreator.js:

```
placeAddedHandler = () => {
this.props.onAddEvent(
  this.state.controls.eventName.value,
  this.state.controls.eventDescription.value,
  this.state.controls.location.value
);
};

render() {
return(
  <LinearGradient style={styles.linearGradient} colors={['#718792', '#1c313a', '#000a12']}>
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
      <SetLocationMap 
        mapContainer={styles.mapContainer}
        onLocationPick={this.locationPickedHandler}
        showUserLocation={true}
      />
    </View>
    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.placeAddedHandler}>
        <View style={styles.button}>
          <Text style={{color: 'black', fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Add</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  </LinearGradient>
);
} 
}
```

SetLocationMap.js:

```
  pickLocationHandler = (event) => {
const coords = event.nativeEvent.coordinate;
//For animation of map
this.map.animateToRegion({
  ...this.state.focusedLocation,
  latitude: coords.latitude,
  longitude: coords.longitude
});
this.setState(prevState => {
  return {
    focusedLocation: {
      ...prevState.focusedLocation,
      latitude: coords.latitude,
      longitude: coords.longitude
    },
    locationChosen: true
  };
});
this.props.onLocationPick({
  latitude: coords.latitude,
  longitude: coords.longitude
});
};

  render() {
let marker = null;
if(this.state.locationChosen) {
  marker = <MapView.Marker coordinate={this.state.focusedLocation} flat={true}/>
}
return(
  <View style={this.props.mapContainer}>
    {/* <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.getLocationHandler} style={styles.iconContainer}>
      <Icon name="md-locate" size={30} color="blue"/>
    </TouchableOpacity> */}
    <MapView
      {...this.props}
      style={styles.map}
      initialRegion={this.state.focusedLocation}
      onPress={this.pickLocationHandler}
      ref={ref => this.map = ref} //For animating map movement
    >
      {marker}
    </MapView>
  </View>
);
}
}
```

Here are my codes for React Redux:

```
../store/reducers/events.js - this is where I put my React Redux State

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
  case ADD_EVENT:
    return {
       ...state,
      events: state.events.concat({
        key:  `${Math.random()}`,
        name: action.eventName,
        description: action.eventDescription,
        location: action.location,
        image: {
          uri: "https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4096/4744241983_34023bf303_b.jpg"
        }
      })
    };
```

> If there something missing, ask me for my codes. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

May be the problem in your code is this :

```
<MapView.Marker key={index} coordinate={this.props.events}>
```

Where **this.props.events** is something (according to your state) different to location type.

An attempt of solution is to try to provider a location type like :

```
<MapView.Marker key={index} coordinate={{latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude}}>
```

where **latitude** and **longitude** are float number.

Example :

```
<MapView.Marker key={index} coordinate={{latitude: 4.3414303 , longitude: 15.3277476}}>
```

**Update** :
If your intention is to display location providing by events in your state you can do : I assume that location in your state is a location type ({ latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude }), you can loop directly this.props.events :

```
<MapView
      style={styles.container}
      initialRegion={this.state.focusedLocation}
      onPress={this.pickLocationHandler}
      showsUserLocation={true}
      ref={ref => this.map = ref} //For animating map movement
    >
      {userMarker}
      {this.props.events.map((marker, index) => {
        if(marker.location.latitude && marker.location.longitude) {
            const scaleStyle = {
              transform: [
                {
                  scale: interpolations[index].scale,
                },
              ],
            };
            const opacityStyle = {
              opacity: interpolations[index].opacity,
            };
            return (
              <MapView.Marker key={index} coordinate={marker.location}>
                <Animated.View style={[styles.markerWrap, opacityStyle]}>
                  <Animated.View style={[styles.ring, scaleStyle]} />
                    <View style={styles.marker} />
                </Animated.View>
              </MapView.Marker>
            );
        } else {
            return null;
        }
      })}
    </MapView>
```

Comment: How can I access my longitude and latitude in my Redux Store with using your Example/Answer/Suggestion?

Comment: I have a curious question, does the error will appear if I do not have any value in my Redux Store of `location` or the `events` (longitude and latitude)?

Comment: Yes you should provide a coordinate. I have some question : 

1- what is the type of **this.props.events** : array, string or ... ?
2- when you are looping the variable **this.state.markers** with map instruction, i assume that you want to display several markers to the map, please can you try to tell how you set this variable?

Comment: 1. It is array, with 2 strings, 1 image, and the value of location (longitude and latitude).

2. Yes I want to display several markers to the map. I set this variable using the `map` to test if it will work display several markers on the map. Furthermore, I set this variable to use it for animation because I have Animated.ScrollView (5 Card) so everytime I swipe each card have it will navigate it to their own latitude and longitude.

I will add the code for my `this.state.markers` on my Question. Thank you!

Comment: I updated my answer in case you want to display location of every event in your state.

Comment: I tried it and it looks it will work but it gives me error. It says `latlng cannot be null - a position is required.`

Comment: I updated again my answer : I hope this can fix the issue.

Comment: Still got the same error. I observe, i still get the state of `location` and its value (latitude and location). Maybe mistake is pointing out the longitude and latitude. I'll try different approach.

Comment: Or i think the wrong one is the `coordinate` of the `MapView.Marker` I think it is still pointing the state array of `markers`? Instead of the state in Redux?

Comment: Or maybe it is `this.props.events.location.value`?

Comment: I added all my Components to understand more the flow of the App

Comment: Thank you for the effort @William Bridge ! Without you this will be harder for me to solve. Already solved, see my edited codes. Now my problem is with the animation but same issues about Redux.

Comment: In EventCreator.js precisely in **placeAddedHandler()** function, please could you give us the definition of **onAddEvent()** props function ?

Comment: Also, in EventCreator.js precisely in placeAddedHandler() function, what is the type of **this.state.controls.location.value** ?

Comment: The `onAddEvent()` is function to dispatch the State into my Redex Store and `placeAddedHandler()` I use this for the `onPress` of my `TouchableOpacity`.

Comment: `this.state.controls.location.value` is the state of my `location` and `latitude` inside my EventCreator Component